# Storm, HDFSBolt

Tags: hdfs, apache-storm

I'm trying to implement `HDFSBolt` in `Storm`. I wanted to start with basic one, so used `TestWordSpout` provided by `Storm`.

I can successfully compile the `topology`, but when I submit it I get the following error

```
8102 [Thread-17-output-executor[3 3]] ERROR o.a.s.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/CanUnbuffer
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_95]
        .......
        .......
```

Here is my `topology`

```
public class HdfsFileTopology {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    RecordFormat format = new DelimitedRecordFormat().withFieldDelimiter(",");
    SyncPolicy syncPolicy = new CountSyncPolicy(100);
    FileRotationPolicy rotationPolicy = new FileSizeRotationPolicy(10.0f, Units.KB);
    FileNameFormat fileNameFormat = new DefaultFileNameFormat().withPath("/user");
    HdfsBolt bolt = new HdfsBolt()
            .withFsUrl("hdfs://localhost:9000")
            .withFileNameFormat(fileNameFormat)
            .withRecordFormat(format)
            .withRotationPolicy(rotationPolicy)
            .withSyncPolicy(syncPolicy);

    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("word", new TestWordSpout(), 1);
    builder.setBolt("output", bolt, 1).shuffleGrouping("word");
    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setDebug(true);
    conf.setNumWorkers(3);
    StormSubmitter.submitTopology("HdfsFileTopology", conf, builder.createTopology());
    }
}
```

And this is my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
  <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
<artifactId>storm-test</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>storm-test</name>

<properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <provided.scope>provided</provided.scope>
</properties>
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>intellij</id>
    <properties>
        <provided.scope>compile</provided.scope>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hdrhistogram</groupId>
    <artifactId>HdrHistogram</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.8.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
    <artifactId>fest-assert-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0M8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmock</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.3</version>
   </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <scope>${provided.scope}</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>multilang-javascript</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>multilang-ruby</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>multilang-python</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-metrics</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-redis</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<sourceDirectory>src/jvm</sourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>test/jvm</testSourceDirectory>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/multilang</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                        <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass></mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.theoryinpractise</groupId>
    <artifactId>clojure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <sourceDirectories>
        <sourceDirectory>src/clj</sourceDirectory>
      </sourceDirectories>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>compile</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <executable>java</executable>
      <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
      <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
      <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
      <mainClass>${storm.topology}</mainClass>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Sound like a jar packaging problem. Make sure that your jar contains a required dependencies.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I checked it out, seems like I have included all the dependencies

Comment: Are you sure, that the jar you submit to storm contains those, too? Just having the dependencies in pom.xml does not necessary guarantee that your jar contains them...

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Yes, it has `storm-hdfs`, `hadoop`, etc.

Comment: If `org/apache/hadoop/fs/CanUnbuffer` is contained in your jar, I have no idea why it is not found.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax It has `hadoop-hdfs`, `hadoop-common` etc and etc, but not `fs` (just noticed). How can I include it into jar?

Comment: Can you share the part of your pom file that assembles your jar file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102728/discussion-between-user3053089-and-matthias-j-sax).

Comment: I usually use `maven-jar-plugin` in combination with `maven-dependency-plugin` to assembly the jar. Have a look here for an example: https://github.com/mjsax/aeolus/blob/master/queries/lrb/pom.xml The `<includes>` section in `maven-jar-plugin` lists additional dependencies. `maven-dependency-plugin` make those dependent files available (eg, commons-lang3). As far as I know `maven-shade-plugin` can also be used to assemble the jar (read the documenation to get more infos).

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thank you, it works now :)

Comment: Great! I just summarized this discussion as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like a jar packaging problem. Make sure that your jar contains a required dependencies (just having the dependencies in `pom.xml` does not necessary guarantee that your jar contains them).

I usually use `maven-jar-plugin` in combination with `maven-dependency-plugin` to assembly the jar. Have a look here for an example: https://github.com/mjsax/aeolus/blob/master/queries/lrb/pom.xml

The `<includes>` section in `maven-jar-plugin` lists additional dependencies. `maven-dependency-plugin` make those dependent files available (eg, `commons-lang3`).

As far as I know `maven-shade-plugin` can also be used to assemble the jar (read the documenation to get more infos).

Answer (score 1):

I've got alot of those NoClassDefFoundError when my topology was build on storm libraries with version, differs from what I've got on my cluster. Make sure that you use right version.